# How do I check a radio button dynamically in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to check the radio button if the type.location=='none' but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let type of topping.type">
    <input 
        type="radio" class="mr-1" name="{{topping.name}}" 
       id="{{type.location}}" [(ngModel)]="topping.location" 
        [value]="type.location"
        checked="type.location=='none'">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: enclose checked in square brackets `[checked]`

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: You can't use `ngModel` and `checked` together.

Comment: it's only `topping.location='none'`, and yes, not use [checked]

Answer (score 1):

The code works as is, I forgot to set the type.location field to 'none' in the database so the radio was not checked in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[checked]=" type.location==='none' ? true : false" 
||
[checked]="type.location=='none'"
```

instead of

```
checked="type.location=='none'"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table *ngIf="optionList">  
    <tr *ngFor="let op of optionList; let i = index">
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" (CONDITION HERE)"> 
          <label>{{op.option_text}} </label> 
      <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```